Plotting Heatmap
I'm facing an issue with rendering a heatmap plot using  Seaborn where the graph appears incomplete.Could anyone provide insights into what might be causing this incomplete rendering or suggest possible solutions to resolve it?
Below is a simplified version of the code I'm using:
    selected_features = ['Survived', 'Pclass', 'Age', 'SibSp', 'Parch','Fare']
    subset_df = df[selected_features]
    
    #Computing the correlation matrix for the selected features
    correlation_matrix = subset_df.corr()
      sns.set(rc={'figure.figsize':(10,8)})
sns.heatmap(correlation_matrix ,annot = True, cmap = 'coolwarm', square=True)


hey, we would need some more stuff to be able to help you. For instance, we don't see your plot and we don't have your data

Please check the plot I attached it @Tino D

tried removing this? sns.set(rc={'figure.figsize':(10,8)})

also try removing square = True

I tried to remove both but it still the same

can you include a portion of your data for testing?

You seem to be using matplotlib 3.1.1 (4 years old now).


Script given by is looking incomplate, let me share the correct code with Sample DataFrame
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
data = {
    'Survived': [1, 0, 1, 0, 0],
    'Pclass': [1, 2, 3, 1, 2],
    'Age': [22, 38, 26, 35, 27],
    'SibSp': [1, 0, 3, 1, 0],
    'Parch': [0, 0, 1, 1, 0],
    'Fare': [7.25, 71.28, 7.92, 53.1, 8.05]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

selected_features = ['Survived', 'Pclass', 'Age', 'SibSp', 'Parch', 'Fare']
subset_df = df[selected_features]
correlation_matrix = subset_df.corr()
sns.set(rc={'figure.figsize':(10,8)})
sns.heatmap(correlation_matrix, annot=True, cmap='coolwarm', fmt=".2f", square=True)
plt.title('Correlation Heatmap of Selected Features')
plt.show()


hey, nice initiative, just don't post it as an answer. Suggest an edit to the post instead
